# CRUD, create and update functionality on same view : ASP.net MVC2 + EF

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am a newbie and is making web application in Visual Studio 2010 using MVC2 + Entity framework.

I have a situation in which I want to put both operations i.e create user / update user at same view, I have also tried attaching relevant picture where I have made two portions one for create user and second for manage users.

My 'create user' fields are at top of website and when user click 'create button' page got refreshed and all enlisted users gets displayed on same view under second portion 'manage users' showing link to edit/delete them.

I want that when I click on edit link, that particular entity fields get populated on same view in first portion 'create user' where I can modify them and press 'update button'

### **VIEW**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Admin.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="MyNamespace"  %>

<h4>Create New User</h4>
<form method="post" action="/Lignum/CUser">
   <label for="inputEmail3">Full Name</label>
   <input type="text" name="Fullname" id="txtFullname" >
   <label for="inputEmail3">Email</label>
   <input type="email" name="Email" id="Email1">
   <button id="btnCUser" class="btn btn-primary">Create</button>
</form>

<h4>Manage Users</h4>
<table>
  <tr>
     <td>Sr#</td><td>Name</td><td>Email</td><td></td>
  </tr>                 
<% int i=0;
foreach (MyWebsite.Models.User objUser in ViewData.Model as IEnumerable<MyWebsite.Models.User>)
{%>
  <tr>
     <td><%= ++i%></td>
     <td><%= objUser.Fullname%></td>
     <td><%= objUser.Email%></td>
     <td>
         <a href="/Controller/Edit/<%= objUser.UserId %>">Edit</a>
     </td>
  </tr>                             
<%}%>
</table>
```

### **CONTROLLER**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View("UserMgt", _repositoryUser.SelectAll());
}

public ActionResult Edit(object Id)
{
    if (Id != null && Id.ToString().Trim().Length > 0)
    {
        int param = int.Parse(Id.ToString());
        return View("UserMgt", _repositoryUser.SelectByID(Id));
    }
    return View("404");
}
```

Comment: Yes, you can do this easily enough, but you need to show what you have tried so far.

Comment: @StephenMuecke, i have mentioned my code... can you kindly look into it

Comment: I've downvoted, partly because of the request for urgency, and partly because the two substantial answers below did not elicit much of a response from you (other than posters should "look into" your question). If you can post a resolution here, either by virtue of accepting an answer, writing your own or commenting that the question was abandoned, I shall be happy to undownvote (and vote to close if necessary). Thanks!

Comment: @halfer: i ve marked most suitable answer as correct, thanks for pointing :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to make use of JQuery & Ajax to achieve this. Your page is getting refreshed most likely because your are submitting a form. Instead of form submit, you need to attach a function to handle onclick event.

In that function you will know which item is clicked, load the data to be edited from the server sending an ajax request with item id.

When request return you can then open a JQuery popup window or update page's html to display data. User will be allowed to make changes and on Ok button click you can again send the data back to server to save.

I am looking for an example online to refer to you as my code is little complex. You can also look for an example online.

**UPDATE:**

> i want that when i click on edit link, that particular entity fields
>   get populated on same view in 1st portion 'create user' where i can
>   modify them and press 'update button'

Ok, looked at your code. As I said earlier you will need to define an "id" for each html element, the value will be `objUser.UserId` (you can prefix something if you want). Now define a click event for all html elements i.e. .

For a working example refer this [link](http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/mvc/42R0171112-CRUD-Operations-using-jQuery-dialog,-Entity-Framework-and-ASP.NET-MVC.html).

I suggest you progress as you gain some insight and post updated code. We will suggest what's needed for next step. This way you would learn more.

Comment: SBirthare i ve shared my code over here... can you kindly look into it

Comment: @tango - Updated my answer. I am afraid I will not be able to update your code and make it work. You give it a try as advised.

Answer (score 1):

You can try following:

- Create a View model with whatever you need on the create page i.e. user details
- strongly bind your view with this view model
- Have three action methods in controller "Create","Populate" and "Update" with Update and Populate taking Id of the entity as input (you can choose better names)
- Initially call Create method which will just return an empty view model with your View
- Have a hidden variable in view which will store the Id of the entity (in case of create this will be zero)
- on click of create just take the value of this hidden variable and do a post to Update action method.In this case if it is new entity id will be zero
- On click of edit go call Populate method with id of the entity which again will return ViewModel with entity details loaded to the same create view (also set the hidden variable with id)
- In your update method based on the id perform create or update operation i.e. Create for zero and Update for 1

If you post your code or other details I can give some more details using code.

EDIT: OK few more details in terms of code.

```
//This is the view model you need to bind to your view
   public class UserViewModel
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public List<Users> UserList {get;set;} //For binding to the grid
}
```

Below are the action methods in controller.

```
public ActionResult Create()
    {

        var viewModel = new UserViewModel();
        //Logic: Create empty view model for create
        return View("UserMgt", viewModel);
    }

    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        var viewModel = new UserViewModel();
        //Logic: populate the view model based on the id
        return View("UserMgt", viewModel);
    }
    // Call this method using Jquery ajax
    public bool Update(UserViewModel user)
    {
        if (user.Id == 0)
            //Logic : Create the user
        else
        //Logic : Edit the user

        return Json(status); //Status = true if successful else false
    }
```

Initially call create.On click of edit call Edit method.On click of save call Update.
For using jquery ajax follow below link

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: i ve uploaded my code... can you kindly look into it